# Count how many ul tags has number of specific content and display them only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like below format. I don't want to display contents twice. For instance text 'Issue 1' is repeaded 4 times in first ul tag. I want it to be shown once using javascript/jquery. Thanks.

```
<h3>Year 2010</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a href="2010/1/2">Issue 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/1">Issue 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/2">Issue 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/1">Issue 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/1">Issue 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/1">Issue 1</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Year 2011</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a href="2010/1/2">Issue 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/1">Issue 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/2">Issue 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="2010/1/2">Issue 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So why did you put it there in the first place? Or what did generate that html?

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ which is nice for iterating over selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var issues = [];
    $(this).find('li a').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        if($.inArray(text, issues) > -1){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }else{
            issues.push(text);
        }
    });
});
```

It loops over each `ul` and then loops through each `li a` within them. It stores the text of each `ul`'s `a` elements in an array (`issues`).

For each `li a` it checks whether the text has already been added to the array (i.e. it's a duplicate). If it has then it deletes the parent `li`, if it hasn't then it adds it to the array.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/3kr2m/1/

Comment: Thanks Joe, this worked form me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native *JavaScript* solution using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to convert *NodeList* to *Array* and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop (using `forEach` directly on the *NodeList* seemed to have some problems), followed by a [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) on nodes similar to what we have seen previously.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')) // <ul>s to Array
    .forEach( // loop over them
        function (ul) {
            var text = {}; // record what we have seen
            Array.prototype.slice.call(ul.childNodes) // <li>s to Array
                .forEach(  // loop over these
                    function (li) {
                        if (li.nodeType !== 1 || li.tagName !== 'LI')
                            return; // only care about <li>s
                        if (text[li.textContent])
                            ul.removeChild(li); // seen it, remove
                        text[li.textContent] = 1; // mark seen
                    }
                );
        }
    );
```

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5W5j/)

Of course, you could use `for` or `while` loops instead, which would be a little faster but requires you to keep track of more variables..

```
var ul, li, i, j, text;
ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (i = 0; i < ul.length; ++i) { // loop over <ul>
    text = {}; // reset seen for each <ul>
    li = ul[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0; j < li.length; ++j) { // loop over <ul> children
        if (li[j].nodeType === 1 && li[j].tagName === 'LI') { // only <li>
            if (text[li[j].textContent]) ul[i].removeChild(li[j]); // remove seen
            text[li[j].textContent] = 1; // mark seen
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo of this**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5W5j/1/)